# Access date not showing in references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieee-style, bibliographystyle

I am using the ieeetr reference style for my document, however, the references are missing the access date.

For example, I have a reference showing as:

```
OpenCV. Feature Matching, 2014
```

When it should be:

```
OpenCV. Feature Matching, 2014 (accessed Oct. 2, 2023).
```

I have checked by bib file and the entry shows what I assume to be the value used for the access date as:

```
@misc{OpenCV2014,
author = {OpenCV},
booktitle = {OpenCV 3.0.0-dev documentation},
pages = {1},
title = {{Feature Matching}},
url = {http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py{\_}tutorials/py{\_}feature2d/py{\_}matcher/py{\_}matcher.html},
urldate = {2023-10-02},
year = {2014}
}
```

I am setting the reference style via: `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`  and I have checked the documentation from IEEE which still states that the access date should be used for online sources: https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf

Could anyone recommend how I can get the access dates showing for online sources?

EDIT:
Minimal working example as requested:

Tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
  test \cite{OpenCV2014}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}  
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example others can copy and test as is. Note that unless the bibtex style have support for `urldate` it will just be ignored.

Comment: And where exactly does `ieetr.bst` come from? It is not known to CTAN

Comment: From my understanding the ieeetr is a supported style - https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibtex_bibliography_styles

Comment: @daleif - `ieeetr` is one of Oren Patashnik's original bibliography styles for BibTeX. When I type `kpsewhich ieeetr.bst` at a command prompt on my system (MacTeX2023), the reply is `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/ieeetr.bst`.

Comment: I notice that Mendely is producing my bib file with web sources saved as @misc which is then matching with the ieeetr entry for misc within the bst file. I assume this is the source of the issue?

Comment: @Mico apparently I copyed one less `e`

Comment: If you look inside `ieeetr.bst` you'll notice that `urldate` is not mentioned, and thus is nut supported. Probably better to manually write the info in the `note` field.

Comment: @daleif thanks for the advice, while not the most elegant approach given my deadline fast approaching I think it'll do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors of syntax and of logic in your code.

- The `@misc` entry type is BibTeX's "catch-all" entry type, i.e., it is meant to be used only if one of the other pre-defined entry types can't be used for some reason. As such, it's not designed to handle fields such as `booktitle` and `pages`.
- Why do you "escape" underscore characters that are present in URL strings? Doing so pretty much guarantees that your readers won't be able to follow the URLs to their intended destinations. Do yourself a huge favor and load the `xurl` package, which redefines the `\url` command in a way that permits line breaks anywhere in a long URL string.
- The `ieeetr` bibliography style is one of BibTeX's original bib styles and, as such, predates the creation of the WWW by a considerable time span. Yup, we're talking about the early to mid 1980s. Hence, quite unsurprisingly (for most...), the `ieeetr` bib style does *not* know what to do with -- and hence simply ignores -- fields such as `url` and `urldate`.
- I suggest you switch ASAP from the nearly-prehistoric `ieeetr` bib style to the much more recent `IEEEtran` bib style, especially as the latter does recognize the `url` entry type. (You should also load the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers`.)

  However, contrary to your implied assertion, the `IEEEtran` bib style does *not* recognize the `urldate` entry type either. (A question: what is the basis for your claim that BibTeX may reasonably be expected to output "(accessed Oct. 2, 2023)" as part of the formatted bibliographic entry -- with either the `ieeetr` or the `IEEEtran` bib style?) You may want to follow @daleif's suggestion to replace `urldate = {2023-10-02},` with `note = {(accessed Oct. 2, 2023)}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{OpenCV2014,
author    = {OpenCV},
xbooktitle= {OpenCV 3.0.0-dev documentation},
xpages    = {1},
title     = {{Feature Matching}},
url       = {http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html},
urldate   = {2023-10-02},
year      = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xurl} % for flexible version of \url command
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\cite{OpenCV2014}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```